# How to link a .lib library in Windows?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I'm writing c++ code which uses a library "ice.lib". I wish I could link the library to the object file I made, so I wrote the following in `Makefile`:

```
server: Server.o
    c++ -o server Server.o Messager.o -L$(ICE_LIB_PATH) -lice
```

Where (ICE_LIB_PATH) is the location of ice.lib.

The cmd then rains me "undefined reference" errors indicating that I did not link the library at all. I have searched through Internet but no post has talked about how to deal with .lib files. Pls someone help me! Many thanks!

Comment: It isn't Microsoft's (cl.exe). c++ is part of the gnu gcc compiler, make sure ICE_LIB_PATH points to the directory not to the file

Comment: `ICE_LIB_PATH` is pointing to a directory. To be exact, `ICE_LIB_PATH = E:/Ice-3.5.0/lib/x64`

Comment: are you using gcc on windows?

Comment: If this is the GNU toolchain, shouldn't the library be called    libice.lib  or libice.a ?

Comment: @ZoomIn I'm using the compiler from MinGW. The compiler is c++.exe

Comment: @Photon I'm using this ICE tool from ZeroC, where in the `/lib` folder none of the files are named as "libxxx.a". "ice.lib" is the file name

Comment: How did you install the lib? Could be it used the microsoft compiler to build if you have an installation of it on your machine. I once had the same prob with boost.

Comment: @g-makulik it was a .msi file from the official website.

Comment: Then you most likely have a library supposed to be linked with the MS compiler. I'm not sure if there's a way to link it using MinGw GCC.

Comment: @g-makulik How should I do it then? Can I do it without MSVC? I'm more familiar with writing Makefiles and it is better for me as I'm still learning programing

Comment: You can still use makefiles (and even Eclipse IDE should you be working with it). There's a free version (Express) of Visual Studio available, that also installs the compiler of course. You don't need to use Visual Studio IDE, if you don't want that.

Comment: Thanks! I found the `cl.exe`.  Please leave an answer so I can accept it!